# Spring Boot generate test package

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, package

I have Spring Boot application with some test classes. I successfully deploy application as `war` package.

But I also want to produce a package, which allows me to run test from command line. For example:

```
java -jar MyAppTest.jar
```

How make such package?

**EDIT:**
My problem is a little different then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052694/how-do-i-include-test-classes-and-configuration-in-my-war-for-integration-testin) because I don't want to make `war` with tests. I want to have an executable package which runs a specific test (or all tests) in command line.

This is why I asked for possibility of making a `jar` package, which will execute my test as an application (not web-application). This test does some database and diagnostic operations - so this class is integrated with Spring Boot by `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` annotation. It has access to Spring Boot application context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include test classes and configuration in my war for integration testing using maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052694/how-do-i-include-test-classes-and-configuration-in-my-war-for-integration-testin)

Comment: @kryger Explanation why your question is different then mine is included in question edit section. I hope that now my question is more understandable. But thanks for your contribution.