# Arquillian RunAsClient Injecting Stub into WAR to resolve dependency injection

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, war, ear, jboss-arquillian

Hi I have a project setup as follows:

- my-web-project (parent)
- my-web-project-ear
- my-web-project-ejb
- my-web-project-war (contains REST resource @GET method)
- my-web-project-testsuite-integration-jee (contains Arquillian)

---

```
@Stateless
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public final class CmEventsNbiIT {
    @RunAsClient
    @Test
    public void getRequestTest() {
        try {
            final CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/config-mgmt/event/events");
            final CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            assertHalFormattedResponse(response);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void assertHalFormattedResponse(final CloseableHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        Assert.assertNotNull(response);
        final String bodyStr = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Assert.assertTrue(bodyStr.contains("Web Service says HELLO"));
    }
}
```

---

Here is the REST resource that handles the event/events context:

```
@Path("/event")
public class RestResource {
    private static final String SAMPLE_HAL_RESPONSE =
            "{\"_links\":{\"self\":{\"href\":\"/event/events\"}},\"status\":\"PARTIAL\",\"events\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"operationType\":\"CREATE\","
                    + "\"timestamp\":\"2000-02-12T10:11:23Z\",\"targetName\":\"aTargetName\",\"moClass\":\"anMoClass\",\"moFdn\":\"anMoFdn\","
                    + "\"newAttributeValues\":[{\"attributeName\":\"attributeValue\"},{\"anotherAttributeName\":\"anotherAttributeValue\"}]}]}";

    @Inject
    EventService service;

    @GET
    @Produces({ HAL_JSON })
    @Path("/events")
    public Response getEvents(@Context final UriInfo uriInfo) {
        final List<Event> events = service.findEvents(null);

        // THIS FAILS BECAUSE EventService INJECTION fails.
        // return Response.ok("Web Service Events Num = " + events.size(), HAL_JSON).build();

        // WORKS PERFECTLY!
        return Response.ok(SAMPLE_HAL_RESPONSE, HAL_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

---

- The default implementation for EventService lives in my-web-project-ejb.
- The Arquillian runs perfectly if I comment out the @Inject EventService in RestResource and returns the sample JSON.
- The Arquillian is intended to run as a Client but what I want to do is STUB the EventService with a test stub to return sample data but from the EventService implementation and not the RestResource.
- The web app is deployed as an ear in a maven build.

QUESTION: Is there anyway I can pass a test stub as an implementation to be picked up by the deployed war? Or do I have to build up this war locally in the Arquillian test?

Comment: You could use cdi alternatives to give a sort of test double.  But it will require modifying the war.  Any reason you are packing an ear?

Comment: Hi John, we are deploying an ear in a JBOSS container. It is part of a standard git-repo designation when we are assigned a new project. Everything is deployed as ears in these containers in our application. I just noticed that testing aside - the CDI does not find an implementation for EventService. The default impl lives in my EJB project (under the parent maven project) and trying to add a local Deployment with a test stub applied - still is not found on @Inject or EJB :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include test classes and configuration in my war for integration testing using maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052694/how-do-i-include-test-classes-and-configuration-in-my-war-for-integration-testin)